# Hebrew New Testament with cantillation marks

Tags: new-testament

Hebrew manuscripts of the Hebrew Tanakh feature *taʿamim* or “cantillation marks” incorporated by the Masoretes.

Are there any Hebrew translations of the New Testament that feature cantillation marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stu W wrote,

> the New Testament is not sung, it is spoken--even in Messianic Jewish temples to my knowledge. As such you will not find cantillation symbols specific to cadence because no such cadence exists. By the 19th century, Hebrew had tense, and no such cadence was necessary for comprehension.

My research has yielded a contrary answer. According to Wikipedia, on the entry “[Cantillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation),” section “[In Christian missionary uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation#In_Christian_missionary_uses),” it states,

> The Jewish born Christian convert Ezekiel Margoliouth translated the New Testament to Hebrew in 1865 with cantillation marks added. It is the only completely cantillated translation of the New Testament. The translation was published by the London Jews' Society.

The following is an image of [Matt. 1:1](https://archive.org/stream/MargoliouthHebrewNewTestament/Hebrew_nt_part1_margoliouth#page/n3/mode/2up) featuring the cantillation marks:

[image: Margoliouth, Ezekiel.]

---

### References

Margoliouth, Ezekiel. [הברית החדשה על פי המשיח עם נקודות וטעמים](https://archive.org/details/MargoliouthHebrewNewTestament) (*The New Testament according to the Messiah with Vowel Points and Cantillation Marks*). London: London Jews’ Society, 1923.

Comment: You apparently found one. My follow up would then be, who sang it that way, and why? Also, the term I learned distinguishing marks for vowels, pauses, and punctuation from cadence indicators was "tropes," but it seems "cantillation" is specific when I looked it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a very nice pdf version of Margoliuth at http://www.jer-31.com. Singing the text makes complete sense for those who come out of Orthodox Judaism. It's much easier to memorize a song than prose. And it is much easier to join in to the recitation of a text if there is a common agreement on the way it is to be recited.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.